# Close dropdown in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
<select open={false} autoFocus={true} onClick={this.handleClick} size={5}>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

I have made a dropdown, but I cannot close it. I do not want close it with `display:none`

Comment: You have set the size to 5. So every time dropdown list shows 5 items. If you want to close it after selecting one, you can dynamically set it to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially show 5 items and, after selecting close it(set to 1 using a state)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [defaultSize, setDefaultSize] = useState(5);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setDefaultSize(1);

    // do other stuff
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select open={false} autoFocus={true} onClick={handleClick} size={defaultSize}>
        <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
        <option value="lime">Lime</option>
        <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
        <option value="mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the size attribute. change onClick to onChange add value attribute for select tag

```
 <select value={myCar} onChange={handleChange}>
```

Comment: i use size attribute to open drop down default.
i am looking for solution with size attribute